# How can I override HTML body bgcolor attribute with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing an external user stylesheet for an old HTML page that specifies the background colour in the body tag: `<BODY BGCOLOR="#808000">` (*note*: I can't edit the HTML).

I've tried writing the obvious stylesheet:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

but it has no effect: the original colour remains.

Can it be done with CSS? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine here (I tested it). Are you sure the stylesheet is being imported properly?

Comment: @David: To be fair to the community can you be more specific, what exactly was the problem?

Comment: I was trying to apply the user stylesheet using the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/2108) Firefox extension. And the extension was disabled...

Answer (score 3):

FIX:
I've checked it in my place it works

```
body
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

You can also do

```
<body style="background-color:red"></body>
```